# What is the t-statistic referred to in linear regression (in particular when looking at the summary() function in R)?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I'm learning about regression. In one exercise I was asked some questions about the following output in R giving information about a linear model concerning housing prices in Boston with lots of covariates.

[image]

I don't have previous experience with R, but I'm also a newbie to the theory behind linear regression. We have our model $y=X\beta + \epsilon$, and we've made our fit $\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}$.

I'm fairly confident that the "Estimate" column refers to the corresponding coordinate of $\hat{\beta}$.
The standard error I believe(?) refers to the sample deviation of the corresponding covariate, so $\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_j ((X_1)_j-\overline{X_1})^2 }{n-1}}$, in the case of the first covariate, for example, although I am not sure.

My question is, what student statistic is the t-value referring to, and why is it a student random variable? I've looked up many articles but they are all frustratingly hand-wavy about this type of R output. Even the similar Mathexchange posts I saw didn't help me out.

Comment: The t-statistic is $\hat\beta_i / \text{se}(\hat\beta_i)$. For example, the first row is $36.46/5.103 = 7.144$. The standard error is not the sample standard deviation of the covariate, though, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error

Derivation for linear regression here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression/44841#44841

Comment: I've seen this answer before. I think this is the crux of what I don't understand. $\hat{\beta}_i $ is a random variable that depends on y, sure, but it is only observed one time. How can we speak of standard error? Like for me what you are writing is for example $SE(5)$, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @user51547  As for what standard error is, my professor told me that "The standard error of an estimator/estimate is the square root of its estimated variance.  Hence the standard error is itself a random variable. " which to me meant sample standard deviation. I've been on the Wikipedia page, what I found a bit confusing was that it defines SE as $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, but $\sigma $ is a theoretical value and unknown. So this definition isn't a random variable? But I guess $\sigma$ gets estimated by the sample standard deviation, so I was right up to a factor of $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: And importantly, why does $\frac{ \hat{\beta}_i }{ SE( \hat{\beta}_i ) }$ follow a student distribution?

Comment: Actually, I finally found that everything is super nicely explained here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/understanding-t-test-for-linear-regression